# Python: setting generator Polynomial in zlib.crc32

Tags: python, crc, standard-library

I am trying to use `zlib.crc32` to compute CRC in Python.
I would like to be able to set the generator polynomial of the CRC, but I cannot find any documentation. So the question is: can this be done?

I know that there is `crcmod` library that can do this, but in my case I want to only use standard Python libraries and don't want to install any external library. Is there any standard Python library that can be used to calculate CRC and I can define its generator polynomial?

in `crcmod` it is done as:

```
import crcmod

crc32 = crcmod.Crc(poly=0x104c11db7, rev=True, initCrc=0, xorOut=0xFFFFFFFF)

crc32.update(bytearray(input_string))
```

in the above code the `poly` is the generator polynomial.

Comment: Unless it is there but not mentioned in the documentation, there is no direct way to use the `zlib` module for that.

Comment: Thanks @JohnColeman. Do you know any other standard Python library that can do this?

Comment: I don't think there is any in the standard library. You could implement it in raw python if needed. The Wikipedia article on CRC has a Python implementation (albeit one which seems designed for pedagogy rather than efficiency).

Comment: As I don't have a permission to install a package, can I copy all files of a library to a folder and direct python to look at that folder for the crc files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the polynomial and other CRC parameters are hard-coded in zlib.

However the CRC-32 generated by those parameters *is* the CRC that zlib implements. You can just use `zlib.crc32`.

```
>>> import crcmod
>>> crc32 = crcmod.mkCrcFun(poly=0x104c11db7, rev=True, initCrc=0, xorOut=0xFFFFFFFF)
>>> print(hex(crc32(b'123456789')))
0xcbf43926
>>> import zlib
>>> print(hex(zlib.crc32(b'123456789')))
0xcbf43926
```

*Update:*

From the comments, speed is not important, and they want a different CRC polynomial.

Here is a simple CRC-32 implementation, assuming `rev=True`, for which you can change or parameterize the polynomial, the initial value, and the final exclusive-or:

```
def crc32(msg):
    crc = 0xffffffff
    for b in msg:
        crc ^= b
        for _ in range(8):
            crc = (crc >> 1) ^ 0xedb88320 if crc & 1 else crc >> 1
    return crc ^ 0xffffffff

print(hex(crc32(b'123456789')))
```

Prints: `0xcbf43926`.

If you need something faster, then you'd need to generate a table for a byte-wise table-driven CRC implementation.

*Update:*

As the original poster continues to trickle out tiny bits of information about their actual question in comments (as opposed to simply saying in total what they want to do in the question), we learn that they need to generate a forward CRC as well (`rev=False`), specifically a CRC-32/MPEG-2. So here is the simple code for that:

```
def crc32mpeg2(msg):
    crc = 0xffffffff
    for b in msg:
        crc ^= b << 24
        for _ in range(8):
            crc = (crc << 1) ^ 0x04c11db7 if crc & 0x80000000 else crc << 1
    return crc & 0xffffffff

print(hex(crc32mpeg2(b'123456789')))
```

Prints: `0x376e6e7`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but that generator polynomial I used in `crcmod` was just an example, and I need to change it for my case. Is there any other standard library that can do that?

Comment: Then you should put in the question what CRC you actually want, as opposed to the wrong CRC.

Comment: The CRC that I want will be different for my different cases, so it is not just a fixed polynomial. That is why I am asking if the polynomial can be defined.

Comment: That is not clear from your question either. I thought you just had a single CRC to implement, in which case I would have suggested using crcmod to generate the table and function, and just copy the result into your application. However if you need to keep generating new CRC functions, then you'll need to duplicate all of the functionality of crcmod. You need to write in the question what you are _actually_ trying to do.

Comment: Also, do you care about speed?

Comment: No I don't care about speed.

Comment: Thanks for the code, how did you come up with the polynomial `0xedb88320` while the polynomial in my original question is `0x104c11db7`?

Comment: That's the same polynomial. When the CRC is reversed (`rev=True`), the polynomial is bit-flipped in the implementation. `0xedb88320` is `0x04c11db7` flipped.

Comment: That's a great answer, however, when I tried that code and compared it with CRC32's generated here: https://crccalc.com/ none of them matched. Specifically I am looking to match CRC-32/MPEG-2, thanks so much for your help.

Comment: That code matches "CRC-32" on that site. (Result `0xcbf43926`.)

Comment: Thanks Mark, yes now the code output matches what that website generates. Can you please explain the code a bit? Where does the number 24 in `b << 24` comes from? Also, why do you do 8 iterations in `range(8)` and finally why do you do `& 0x80000000`?

Comment: Mark: I also notice that to match with your code calculation the input format of data on that website has to be selected as ascii, when I change to hex then they don't match. If you can kindly explain why and how to change the code so it works for Hex input that would be great.

Comment: @TJ1 That has nothing to do with the CRC. A CRC is calculated on a sequence of bytes. If you want to first convert a hexadecimal string to a sequence of bytes, there are many ways to do that in Python. `bytes.fromhex()` is the most straightforward.

Comment: If you want a tutorial on CRCs and their calculation, I recommend this [painless guide](http://ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt).

Comment: Thanks for all your support Mark I really appreciate it and accepted your answer.